# Using predicates in Spark JDBC read method

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jdbc

I am pulling data from sql server to hdfs. Here is my snippet for that,

```
val predicates = Array[String]("int_id < 500000", "int_id >= 500000 && int_id < 1000000")

  val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")
      .option("url", dbUrl)
      .option("databaseName", "DatabaseName")
      .option("dbtable", table)
      .option("user", "***")
      .option("password", "***")
      .option("predicates", predicates)
      .load()
```

My Intellij IDE keeps saying that

> "Type mismatch, expected Boolean or Long or Double or String, Actual :
>   Array[String]"

in predicates. Not sure whats wrong with this. Can anyone see whats wrong with this? Also how do I use fetch size here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `option` method accepts only `Boolean`s, `Long`s, `Double`s or `String`s. To pass the `predicates` as an `Array[String]` you have to use the `jdbc` method instead of specifying it in the `format` method.

```
val predicates = Array[String]("int_id < 500000", "int_id >= 500000 && int_id < 1000000")

val jdbcDF = spark.read.jdbc(
  url = dbUrl,
  table = table,
  predicates = predicates,
  connectionProperties = new Properties(???) // user, pass, db, etc.
)
```

You can see an example [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/exercises/spark-exercise-dataframe-jdbc-postgresql.html).

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. it will be great if you can add all the properties on it ( will be useful for anyone looking for it in future.)