# With clause with SQL Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Hi I'm runnig this SQL statment with Spark 2.4.0 :

```
val qry = " WITH tab1 as (select nu_operation from schema.table_001 ) select nu_operation from tab1"
```

and I'm getting

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The error is from DB . so, pushdown query that reached db creates this trouble. here is relevant talk i had earlier that explains how spark jdbc read interprets the SQL request we place and other spark jdbc read types that may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55193501/with-clause-in-spark-sql-context-not-supported/55195481#55195481

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val qry = " WITH tab1 (nu_operation) as (select nu_operation from schema.table_001 ) select nu_operation from tab1"
```

Comment: I already tried but it also didn't work. It seems that the sql is being interpreted before sent to DB.