# How do I set "for fetch only" when querying ibm db2 using the jdbc driver from spark?

Tags: pyspark, db2, databricks, db2-zos

I have some code to query a db2 database that works if I don't include "for fetch only," but returns an error if I do. I was wondering if it's already being done, or how I could set it.

```
connection_url = f"jdbc:db2://{host}:{port}/{database}:user={username};password={password};"

  df = (spark
    .read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")
    .option("url",connection_url)
    .option("query",query)
    .load())
  return(df)
```

Error when I include for fetch only:

`com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=for;`

and the detailed is:

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    162             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    163         else:
--> 164             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    165 
    166     def json(self, path, schema=None, primitivesAsString=None, prefersDecimal=None,

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4192.load.
: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=for;
                 
;), DRIVER=4.25.13
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:810)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b6.a(b6.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k3.c(k3.java:2824)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k3.d(k3.java:2808)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k3.a(k3.java:2234)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.a(k4.java:8242)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.i(ab.java:206)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:96)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.av.i(av.java:150)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k3.al(k3.java:2203)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.bq(k4.java:3730)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.a(k4.java:4609)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.b(k4.java:4182)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.bd(k4.java:780)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.executeQuery(k4.java:745)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.getQueryOutputSchema(JDBCRDD.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:36)
    at   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:323)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:222)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor704.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I've searched ibm's documentation, and stack overflow using every possible permutation I can think of.

I've read documentation about setting the isolation level since I also get a failure when running queries with `with ur` and was thinking that that if I could find out why that fails, I'd understand why `for fetch only` fails, (there's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927379/spark-read-jdbc-db2-with-ur-command) ) but it makes things clear as mud because I couldn't use it to find an analogous solution for `for fetch only`

I've looked at the db2 documentation on ibm's website, and searched stack overflow but this is eluding me.

edit: queries that run and don't run

**Runs in dbvisualizer and pyspark**

```
select
  id_number
from
  myschema.mytable
FETCH FIRST
  10 ROWS ONLY
```

another one

```
select
  id_number
from
  myschema.mytable
```

**Runs in dbvisualizer but not in pyspark**

```
select
  id_number
from
  myschema.mytable
FETCH FIRST
  10 ROWS ONLY FOR FETCH ONLY
```

another one

```
select
  id_number
from
  myschema.mytable
FOR FETCH ONLY
```

edit 2:

an example is that I run this code:

```
connection_url = f"jdbc:db2://{host}:{port}/{database}:user={username};password={password};"

  df = (spark
    .read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")
    .option("url",connection_url)
    .option("query","""
    select
      id_number
    from
      myschema.mytable
    FOR FETCH ONLY
""")
    .load())
  return(df)
```

and it doesn't work. and then I run this code:

```
connection_url = f"jdbc:db2://{host}:{port}/{database}:user={username};password={password};"

  df = (spark
    .read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")
    .option("url",connection_url)
    .option("query","""
    select
      id_number
    from
      myschema.mytable
    -- FOR FETCH ONLY
""")
    .load())
  return(df)
```

and it does work. and then I went into dbvisualizer, and verified that both versions of the query do work, so it's not a syntax error from what I can tell.

dbvisualizer says the database major version is 12 and minor is 1 and I believe it's z/os. I'm using the jdbc driver version 4.25.13 in both pyspark and dbvisualizer downloaded from maven [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2.jcc/db2jcc/db2jcc4)

edit 3:

this query runs fine in db visualizer, but fails in pyspark.

```
    select
      id_number
    from
      myschema.mytable
    FOR READ ONLY
```

Comment: Don't you think showing the actual query that you try to run might be helpful?

Comment: I added some examples of code that run in db visualizer but don't run in pyspark. it's when I add "FOR FETCH ONLY" that a query stops working. I've tried a bunch of variations. It's those three words that causes a problem. "WITH UR" also doesn't work, but I don't use that flag so it's not as big an issue as "FOR FETCH ONLY" not working. Does that help?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same database in both cases? What is the database version and platform?

Comment: I've clarified in edit 2 since it's queries. they point to the same database/connection. like I think it's the only difference...no wrong database. DBvisualizer says the database version is 12 and minor is 1 and I believe the os is z/OS

Comment: I believe that page says "Alternative syntax and synonyms: FOR FETCH ONLY can be specified as a synonym for FOR READ ONLY." I added an edit 3. when I do for read only, it works in dbvisualizer but not in pyspark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I found out what's happening. **tl;dr: spark already does it**.

The documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#data-source-option) states:

> A query that will be used to read data into Spark. The specified query will be parenthesized and used as a subquery in the FROM clause. Spark will also assign an alias to the subquery clause. As an example, spark will issue a query of the following form to the JDBC Source.
>
> SELECT  FROM (<user_specified_query>) spark_gen_alias

I'm fairly certain the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRDD.scala#L313):

```
    val sqlText = options.prepareQuery +
      s"SELECT $columnList FROM ${options.tableOrQuery} $myTableSampleClause" +
      s" $myWhereClause $getGroupByClause $getOrderByClause $myLimitClause $myOffsetClause"
```

So FOR FETCH ONLY falls within the subquery, which is not allowed in DB2.

Fortunately though, it looks like CONCUR_READ_ONLY jdbc option is set, which is equivalent to `FOR READ ONLY` per documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=drija-characteristics-jdbc-resultset-under-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj)

| JDBC setting | Db2® cursor setting | IBM Informix® cursor setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CONCUR_READ_ONLY | FOR READ ONLY | FOR READ ONLY |
| CONCUR_UPDATABLE | FOR UPDATE | FOR UPDATE |
| HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT | WITH HOLD | WITH HOLD |
| TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY | SCROLL not specified | SCROLL not specified |
| TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE | INSENSITIVE SCROLL | SCROLL |
| TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE | SENSITIVE STATIC, SENSITIVE DYNAMIC, or ASENSITIVE, depending on the cursorSensitivity Connection and DataSource property | Not supported |

The relevant code in spark is:

```
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlText,
        ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
```

from [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRDD.scala#L316)

As a side note, it looks like even if it wasn't specified explicitly in the code above, CONCUR_READ_ONLY is the default flag for ResultSet in java sql:

| Concurrency | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY | Creates a read-only result set. This is the default |
| ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE | Creates an updateable result set. |

[source](https://tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-result-sets.htm)