# java.lang.OutofMemorySpace:Java heap space while fetching 120 million rows from database in pyspark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm very new to pyspark/Apache Spark. I need to fetch multiple tables from a database on a server each containing around 120 million rows or more for analysis. I should be able to perform computations on the data. I am running pyspark on a server acting as both master and slave and has 7.45G of RAM.
I have installed the jdbc driver and this is the code that I've used.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

hostname = "xx.xxx.xx.xx"
dbname = "AAA"
jdbcPort = 3306
username = "xxxxx"
password = "yyyyy"

jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{}:{}/{}?user={}&password={}".format(hostname, jdbcPort, dbname, username, password)
query = "(SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME) alias_name"
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', url=jdbc_url, dbtable=query).load()
```

The query loads fine but when I do `df.show()`, it displays the following:

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]20/06/11 11:54:29 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2210)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:470)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3112)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2736)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
20/06/11 11:54:29 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2210)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:470)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3112)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2736)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
20/06/11 11:54:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2210)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:470)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3112)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2736)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

20/06/11 11:54:29 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 380, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaErrorERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
: <exception str() failed>
```

I also read that Spark uses a fraction of the available RAM for computation where the default for driver memory and executor memory is 1024MB and 512MB. 
So I launched pyspark from the terminal using this and implemented the same code shown above:

`pyspark --jars /home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar --driver-memory 7G --executor-memory 7G`

This gets rid of the `java.lang.OutofMemorySpace: Java heap space` error but shows other errors like - `py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty` and `IndexError: pop from an empty deque`

Can someone please explain what's going on, what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You can't get a quart into a pint pot. Consider doing the calculations in SQL at the server.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to load in RAM **too much data**. You should first reduce the amount of data that SQL retrieves you before it reaches **Spark** and optimize it using spark parameters, for example **partitions**.

Consider one or more of these optimizations:

- Specify in `SELECT` what columns to view explicitely, only the ones you need, if possible;
- (Raw query) Loop in a `while` cycle until you can `fetch` rows by looping each row. Following techniques could work by setting a constant `n_rows` to read in memory and updating `i` index each cycling:

`LIMIT i,i+n_rows`

`BETWEEN i AND i+n_rows`

`WHILE primaryKey >= i AND primaryKey < i+n_rows`

- Using **partitions**. Use `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound` and `numPartitions` *[(Reference 1)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/R/read.jdbc.html) and [(Reference 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56535346/13695845)*:

`partitionColumn` select the column that will be used to determine how to split the data (For example, the **primary key**).

`lowerBound` estabilishes the **minimum value** of `partitionColumn` that will be fetched.

`upperBound` estabilishes the **maximum value** of `partitionColumn` that will be fetched.

`numPartitions` means how many parallel connection you want to set for reading data through RDBMS.

So Spark will retrieve you datasets using rows that you would get if you were doing `SELECT * FROM table WHERE partitionColumn BETWEEN lowerBound AND upperBound`.